# Combinatorics: arranging $n$ balls in $k$ cell with condition

Tags: combinatorics, balls-in-bins

Im learning combinatorics, and I came across a question I couldn't find the answer to:

I have $n$ identical balls and $k$ different cells, I want to find the number of ways to arrange the balls with the condition that each cell can have at most $x$ balls where $0\le x<n$.

Without the condition it is just arranging of $n$ balls into $k$ cells and the solution is just $\binom{n+k-1}{k}$

Can someone explain to me how we can add the condition and find the number of permutations.

Thanks

Comment: You could use the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) or find the coefficient of $t^n$ in the expansion of the [generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function) $(1 + t + t^2 + \cdots + t^x)^k$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I couldn't understand how to use it, can you answer, with the guidelines please?